# How to update line while pressing "Shift" key?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to draw straight line with pressing key "Shift".After pressing "Shift" i want to set cursor on line at 45/90 degree angle. While drawing a line on Mouse_Move event.
Diagrammatically i want like this.
[image]

For that i have written code as below:

```
if (isShiftKeyPressed) {

    endX = evt.X;
    endY = evt.Y;
    var deltaX = endX -startX;
    var deltaY = endY - startY;
    var angleInRadian = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    var angleInDegree = angleInRadian * 180 / Math.PI;//error in this line 

    if (deltaX > 0 && deltaY > 0) {
        if (angleInDegree > 45 && angleInDegree < 90) {

          UpdateLastPosition(endX,startY);
        }
        if (angleInDegree < 45 && angleInDegree > 0) {

            UpdateLastPosition(startX,endY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What’s your actual question?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite,T.J. Crowder I am getting if the shift key is down,but i want to restrict my cursor on every 90/45 degree angle(somehow like we see in Microsoft Paint to draw straight line).in that code i am calculating angle to set cursor but it is not properly working.can i get help in that.tell me if you don't get it.

Comment: We understand what you’re trying to achieve, but: “it is not properly working” — you need to describe this part in more detail. Specifically: 1. What do you expect your code to do? 2. What is your code actually doing?

Comment: i need my code to calculate angle between two points.then redraw line at 45 degree(clockwise anticlockwise),and my code is calculating angle between two points.but i am not getting that how to update endpoint of line according to angle(shown in image: B to B').

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're asking how to tell if the shift key is down.

`evt.shiftKey` will be `true` if the shift key was down when the event was generated, `false` if it wasn't.

So your

```
![if (isShiftKeyPressed) {
```

would be

```
if (evt.shiftKey) {
    // The shift key was down when the event was generated
}
else {
    // It wasn't
}
```

*(I assume the `!` before `if` was a typo.)*

[Example](http://jsbin.com/rulitiza/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/rulitiza/1/edit))

Comment: @Paul D. Waite,T.J. Crowder I am getting if the shift key is down,but i want to restrict my cursor on every 90/45 degree angle(somehow like we see in Microsoft Paint to draw straight line).in that code i am calculating angle to set cursor but it is not properly working.can i get help in that.tell me if you don't get it.

Comment: @Shikha: You could do that with [the pointer lock API](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/) on browsers that support it, [demo from MDN here](http://mdn.github.io/pointer-lock-demo/). Fairly clunky, and there is (appropriately) that big warning the first time you do it on a page. But I think you'd be better off just drawing the line at the relevant angle while ignoring where the mouse actually is. I've used several tools that do that (web and not) and it's fine from a UX perspective.